# PHP Cannot get post data from form

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

I want to submit a form that user fill up their information to an api. I have created a wordpress plugin to do it. The problem that I am currently facing is when I call `$_POST["registerId"] or $_POST["password"]` it is empty value.

The following code is all belong to the same page. This function consist of the form and it will call javascript to do validation.

```
function registration_form_layout() {

    ?>

    <h2>Registration Form</h2>

    <script type="text/javascript">

       
        function validate() {

            // Prevent trigger and initialize error
            event.preventDefault()
            var error=""
            var isError = false

            // Retrieve value of the uid, password and confirm password field
            var uid = document.getElementById("form-uid").value;
            var password = document.getElementById("form-password").value;
            var confirmPassword = document.getElementById("form-confirm-password").value;

            // Field declaration
            var uidField = "form-uid"
            var uidErrorField = "error-message-uid"

            var passwordField = "form-password"
            var passwordErrorField = "error-message-password"

            var confirmPasswordField = "form-confirm-password"
            var confirmPasswordErrorField = "error-message-confirm-password"

            var firstUIDCharacter = uid.charAt(0)


            initializeField();

            if ( uid === "" || uid.length < 6 || uid.length > 15 || (firstUIDCharacter >= '0' && firstUIDCharacter <= '9') ) {
                error = "Please enter correct UID"
                generateErrorField(uidField, uidErrorField, error)
                isError = true
            } 

            if ( uid.match(/\d{3,}/) ){
                error="UID last three characters cannot be all numbers"
                generateErrorField(uidField, uidErrorField, error)
                isError = true
            }

            if ( password === "" || password.length < 6 ) {
                error = "Please enter correct password"
                generateErrorField(passwordField, passwordErrorField, error)
                isError = true
            } 

            if ( confirmPassword === "" ) {
                error = "Please enter correct password"
                generateErrorField(confirmPasswordField, confirmPasswordErrorField, error)
                isError = true
            }

            if ( password !== confirmPassword ) {
                error = "The two inputs must be consistent"
                generateErrorField(passwordField, passwordErrorField, error)
                generateErrorField(confirmPasswordField, confirmPasswordErrorField, error)
                isError = true
            }

            if ( password.length > 5 && ( password.match(/^-?\d+$/) || password.search(/[a-zA-Z]/) === -1 ) ) {
                error = "Password must contain both letters and numbers"
                generateErrorField(passwordField, passwordErrorField, error)
                generateErrorField(confirmPasswordField, confirmPasswordErrorField, error)
                isError = true
            }

            if (isError) {
                return false
            } else {
    
                var result = "<?php echo submit_registration(); ?>"
                console.log(result)
                
            }
        }

    </script>
    <p id="php_code"></p>

    <form method="POST" id="registration-form" onsubmit="return validate()">
        <label>UID</label>
        <br/>
        <input type="text" name="registerId" id="form-uid" class="form-control" placeholder="Please enter your login ID"/>
        <p id="error-message-uid" class="error"></p>

        <label>Password</label>
        <br/>
        <input type="password" name="password" id="form-password" class="form-control" placeholder="Please set the new password"/>
        <p id="error-message-password" class="error"></p>

        <label>Confirm Password</label>
        <br/>
        <input type="password" name="confirm_password" id="form-confirm-password" class="form-control" placeholder="Please confirm the new password"/>
        <p id="error-message-confirm-password" class="error"></p>
        <br/>

        <br/>
        <input type="submit" name="form_submit" id="submit-registration" class="form-control" value="Next"/>
        <br/>
    </form>

    <?php
}
add_shortcode('register_form','registration_form_layout');
```

This part of the code will trigger the api and use the $_POST data to submit the data to the api.

```
function submit_registration() {

    $ch = curl_init();

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,"https://localhost/testing/register");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);

    $payload = json_encode( 
        array( 
            "Password"=> $_POST["password"], 
            "RegId"=> $_POST["registerId"], 
        ) 
    );

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $payload );
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type:application/json'));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

    $server_output = curl_exec($ch);
    $error    = curl_error($ch);
    $errno    = curl_errno($ch);
    $httpcode = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);

    $test = json_decode($server_output, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);

    echo '<pre>UID: '.$_POST["registerId"].'Password: '.$_POST["password"].'Server Output:'.status_message($test['Status']);

    curl_close ($ch); 
}
```

Update:
I am required to use curl because if i use ajax. cors origin error will keep appearing.

Comment: The problem is that you're calling `<?php echo submit_registration(); ?>` on page load, not on form submission. Instead, use [AJAX](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_ajax_intro.asp) to call `submit_registration()`.

Comment: You cannot mix JavaScript and PHP like this. echoing the `submit_registration()` function does not make sense.

Comment: @Raptor May I know the proper way to do it?

Comment: @kmoser but i call validate() on form submit

Comment: @kraken `<?php echo submit_registration(); ?>` calls the function on page load. It doesn't matter that you calll `validate()` on form submit.

Comment: // var result = "<?php echo submit_registration(); ?>";
var http = new XMLHttpRequest();
var url = "http://localhost/stackoverflow/register.php";
var params = JSON.stringify({ RegId: uid, Pasword:password });
http.open("POST", url, true);

http.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
http.setRequestHeader("Content-length", params.length);
http.setRequestHeader("Connection", "close");

http.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if(http.readyState == 4 && http.status == 200) {
        alert(http.responseText);
    }
}
http.send(params);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, You cannot mix JavaScript and PHP like this. The structure has to be rewritten completely.

First, create a PHP file called `submit_registration.php`, under the plugin directory, contents are as follow:

```
<?php
// TODO: Add POST isset check and data cleansing
$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,"https://localhost/testing/register");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);

$payload = json_encode( 
    array( 
        "Password"=> $_POST["password"], 
        "RegId"=> $_POST["registerId"], 
    ) 
);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $payload );
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type:application/json'));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

$server_output = curl_exec($ch);
$error    = curl_error($ch);
$errno    = curl_errno($ch);
$httpcode = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);

$test = json_decode($server_output, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);

echo '<pre>UID: '.$_POST["registerId"].'Password: '.$_POST["password"].'Server Output:'.status_message($test['Status']);

curl_close ($ch); 
?>
```

Then, in your registration form, change the `<form>` tag to the following:

```
<form action="<?php echo plugins_url( 'submit_registration.php', __FILE__ ); ?>" method="post" onsubmit="return validate()">
```

and in the `validate()` JS function, you can just return `true` or `false` based on the validation result. Don't submit a form inside the function.

Side Notes:

- Your HTML structure has problems too
- in cURL request, the `json_encode()` is optional
- You should refer to WordPress plugin development guideline to construct your plugin.

Comment: After following your guide, why the pre tag in submit_registration is not triggered?

Comment: have you checked the curl call is executed successfully? Is there any server error? You only defined `$error`, `$errno` and `$httpcode` but you never use it. Also, have you enabled error reporting in PHP?

Comment: Yes curl call does not give any response. there is no server error. I have used it. And on the pre tag there is some word like UID: . If it is executed i believe this pre tag will appear too. I also echo '<p>executing</p>' before curl init but it does not appear too

Comment: Therefore you should check the "API" code or server log. If there is no response, there must be something wrong.

Comment: Server there tested its working have response with postman. Its just not executing the submit_registration.php file

Comment: I have find out what is preventing it from calling submit_registration. in the javascript there is event.preventDefault() which preventing the function from calling it